# What is the difference between compare two date as string with format (Y-m-d h:i:s) and two date with strtotime of date in php?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have confused between two different conditions but gives the same result.

> First Case

```
  $row_otp_time = '2020-10-20 01:59:31';

  $date = new DateTime($row_otp_time);
  $date->modify('+5 minute');
  $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
  date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
  $expired_datetime = $date->format("Y-m-d h:i:s");

  $current_date_time = '2020-10-20 02:04:31'; //current date      

  if($current_date_time > $expired_datetime){
    echo 'expired';
  }
  else{
    echo 'not expired';
  }
```

> Ouput
> `not expired`

---

> Second Case

```
  $row_otp_time = '2020-10-20 01:59:31';

  $date = new DateTime($row_otp_time);
  $date->modify('+5 minute');
  $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
  date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
  $expired_datetime = $date->format("Y-m-d h:i:s");

  $current_date_time = '2020-10-20 02:04:31'; //current date      

  if(strtotime($current_date_time) > strtotime($expired_datetime)){
    echo 'expired';
  }
  else{
    echo 'not expired';
  }
```

> Output
> `not expired`

So in the above two examples, there is one difference is that in first case, I have compared the normal date as string but in the second case, I have compared the date with strtime function and I know that second method is proper to check.

But I want why the first case is not proper or can you explain in which type of cases or some dates example where that first case given improper result.

Also, Is this both type of cases create issue in the date time comparing for any cases?

Comment: first comparison based  on date string, second one based on number.

Comment: Why are you expecting different results?

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I know that but I have edited my question detail with more specifically. I want to know that first case give improper result for some specific date.

Comment: when you need `>` comparison, then number is better than string. Go with second one.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson How the `IF` condition understand date type of string by `PHP`? means it is the normal string then why PHP gives the proper result of comparing the date string.

Comment: Your first code are comparing strings. When you then do a `>`, which is for numbers, PHP converts both strings to numbers. So `2020-xx-xx xx:xx:xx` will just become `2020`. So your first comparison is actually equal to: `if (2020 > 2020)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does PHP compare strings with comparison operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888674/how-does-php-compare-strings-with-comparison-operators)

Comment: @iainn We can say that first case example is the always gives the proper result as per date comparing? How PHP IF condition understand this string is the date or PHP consider the number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$row_otp_time = '2020-10-20 12:52:00';

```
  $date = new DateTime($row_otp_time);
  $date->modify('+5 minute');
  $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
  date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
 
  $current_date_time = '2020-10-20 01:00:00'; // date('Y-m-d h:i:s')

  $expired_datetime = $date->format("Y-m-d h:i:s");

  if(strtotime($current_date_time) > strtotime($expired_datetime)){
    echo 'exxpired';
  }
  else{
    echo 'not expired';
  }
```

If you are getting current date-time like date('Y-m-d h:i:s') (commented code) with small "h" then it will not give compare date strings properly if am/pm is changing