# Check if two hours are between a time range

Tags: php

I allow myself to ask my question here, because after several hours of trying to make my code work, it still does not work!
So I would simply like to check if two times (For example **8:00** and **10:00**) are included between a time range (For example between **8:00** and **9:00**). I have already tried several combinations, it seems to work from time to time, but when I check if 9:00 and 10:00 is between **8:00** and **9:00**, it returns that the time is not included in the time slot when it is supposed to be!
Here is my code for the moment: (all data has been transformed into strtotime())

```
if ((($hdebut >= $ihdebutcours) && ($hdebut <= $ihfincours)) && (($hfin >= $ihdebutcours) && ($hfin >= $ihfincours))) {
    $f++;
}
```

For example :

- `$hdebut` = 9:00
- `$hfin` = 11:15
- `$ihdebutcours` = 9:00
- `$ihfincours` = 10:00

Thank you very much to the people who will help me, it will help me enormously to continue my project, and sorry for my bad English! Good day to you !

Comment: `($hfin >= $ihfincours)` condition is not satisfied that's why it returns false

Comment: No, unfortunately this still does not work!

Comment: Do you know Carbon? This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508963/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-using-carbon-and-blade

Comment: No, not at all, and do you think it can help me to check if two hours are between two other hours?

Comment: You should probably consider converting to `DateTime` objects, or normalize to minutes, or something. Please see https://3v4l.org/COqlK for how strings are compared. ```var_dump(
  '9:00' > '10:00', // true
  '10:00' > '9:00', // false
  '10:00' > '11:00', // false
  '11:00' > '10:00',  // true
);``` etc. so that doesn't really add up does it.

Comment: If you're wondering why that is, `>` and `<` with strings, unless they can be gracefully coerced to numbers (which isn't the case here), is comparison of alphabetical order. ```9:00 > 10:00``` because 9 comes after 1 in the scheme of 0123456789 things. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888674/how-does-php-compare-strings-with-comparison-operators

Comment: Yes, but all data is converted to strtotime(), I put '9:00' or '10:00' to give you an example!

Answer (score 1):

Try PHP's [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php)...

```
<?php

$hdebut = '9:00';
$hfin = '11:15';
$ihdebutcours = '9:00';
$ihfincours = '10:00';

$hdebutDT = new DateTime($hdebut);
$hfinDT = new DateTime($hfin);
$ihdebutcoursDT = new DateTime($ihdebutcours );
$ihfincoursDT = new DateTime($ihfincours);

if ((($hdebutDT >= $ihdebutcoursDT) && ($hdebutDT <= $ihfincoursDT)) && (($hfinDT >= $ihdebutcoursDT) && ($hfinDT >= $ihfincoursDT))) {
    $f++;
}
```

You could even shorten all this by using [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) also perhaps.

Comment: Does this have any real difference with strtotime which I already use? Because by doing this, there is no difference unfortunately!

Comment: Thats odd. When I tested my solution before posting, I initially set `$f` to `0` and ran the code. The result was`$f` was `1`. - i.e. - it worked

Answer (score 0):

It sure is overkilled but when dealing with dates, I often go with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

With Carbon, you could easily check if a date is in the timerange of two dates

```
  $lessonStart = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('today at 9:00');
  $lessonEnd = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('today at 11:15');

  $arrivedAt = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('today at 9:00');
  $endedAt = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('today at 10:00');

  if ($arrivedAt->between($lessonStart, $lessonEnd) && $endedAt->between($lessonStart, $lessonEnd)) {
      //...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem! It was actually the operator! I changed it to "<" instead of "<="! Thank you all for your messages, and again sorry to have disturbed you! Good day to you !

```
($hdebut <= $ihdebutcours AND $ihdebutcours < $hfin) OR ($hdebut < $ihfincours AND $ihfincours <= $hfin)
```