# How to identify now() in if function in php?

Tags: php

So I know some ways to use NOW() to insert something, like:

```
$insert = "insert into users(date) values(NOW())";
```

But I want  something like:

```
if(NOW() > something)
```

Like I want to use NOW In if function,
If its not possible in any ways, what about CURRENT_DATE. like:

```
if(CURRENT_TIME > something)
```

I want it in a correct php form.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The `NOW` function is part of MySQL and if you are doing a comparison in PHP look at the `DATE` functions.

Comment: Have you tried using NOW() in comparisons? It should work just fine.

Comment: `something` is in the database or in PHP?

Comment: I just tried it, it works perfectly, Thanks so much helped aloot, I am struggling with this nearly a month, Again thanks so much!..

Answer (score -1):

I Know my question sounded stupid, but I am just new to PHP and MySQL, the answer is to use comparison like:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

And Put it in if function like:

```
if($today > something)
{
//Action
}
```

Thanks so much for you're help!

Comment: This is not an answer. A string being greater than something doesn't make sense. This likely is not working as you intend. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888674/how-does-php-compare-strings-with-comparison-operators

Comment: @user3783243 it does and your link explains that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).